# Omission of Verb in Compound Sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs, passive-voice

Does the following sentence sound correct in the term of grammar?

"Subscriptions were enabled and auto-renew options disabled."

There is no verb in the second part of the compund sentence. However, this verb can be easily understood from the context.

Is it still better to say: "Subscriptions were enabled and auto-renew options were disabled"? Or maybe we can use a dash instead of the verb ("Subscriptions were enabled and auto-renew options – disabled"?

Please advise.

Comment: Either way.  The omitted verb sounds better and demonstrates a better understanding of usage.

Comment: A separate question is whether you want to describe an action taken or the result of an action taken, a state.

Answer (score 3):

No, do not use a dash there, but the two other ways you have written it above are fine. You can say it and write it with the second "were" or you can leave it omitted as it is considered implicit in the second coordinating clause. Remember it's in the passive voice; therefore, the past participle "disabled" is really acting as though it were the main verb of the clause.

Comment: Grammar purists would object to your claim that the past participle is acting as though it were the main verb of the clause, but your other advice is sound.

Comment: I said because it's passive, it's acting **as though it were** the main verb of the clause. I have used the past subjunctive to show that it is not actually acting as the main verb, but, in essence, it really is. The "were" just links everything in the passive. Basically, I'm trying to say that one cannot omit "disabled" above as it is, in essence, the main verb.